# Where I can find QGIS debug libraries?

Tags: qgis, debugging, dll

I use QGIS 2.12 in my standalone application. Now I want to upgrade my application to the lastest QGIS version (2.16). I use OSGeo4W installer to download all headers, libs and other files. I have three directories with QGIS after installation:

C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis

C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev

C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-rel-dev

In every directory I can find `qgis_core.dll` and `qgis_gui.dll`. But all of them depends from release Qt libraries so I can't debug my application in Visual Studio?

It crashes with error `"Must construct QApplication before QPaintDevice"`.

When I use QGIS 2.12 I had debug and release versions of this libraries.

My question is where I can find debug versions to run my application in debug mode?

Comment: Did this install qgis-rel-dev-pdb? I can see it in osgeo4w-setup, using advanced install (Fortgeschrittene Installation)